# std::bind header file declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, header-files, declaration, stdbind

I want to create a `std::bind` for a function in a cpp file other than my main one, and also in a different namespace. The problem I'm having is how to declare said function in the header file since the binding itself depends on a variable not available to main.cpp.

It is something like this:

function.cpp

```
#include "function.h"
namespace A{
    void function(int i) { ... }   // supposed to be invisible from outside
    namespace A1{
        int varA1;
        auto func = std::bind(A::function, varA1);
    }
    namespace A2{
        int varA2;
        auto func = std::bind(A::function, varA2);
    }
}
```

function.h

```
namespace A{
    namespace A1{
        auto func();
    }
    namespace A1{
        auto func();
    }
}
```

I'm aware the above example does not work, but how do I change the header file in order to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution i can see is to use an `std::function`, since it is pretty much the only object that can take a `bind` object with a defined type.

So, if i read your code correctly, it should return something like:

```
std::function<void()> func();
```

Just to be sure, you are aware that you are declaring functions in your header? To match it, your cpp file should be more like:

```
namespace A1{
    std::function<void()> func() {
        int varA1;
        return std::bind(A::function, varA1);
    }
}
```

Also notice something important, a call to `std::bind` in your case will copy your variable. So if you want your resulting function to see the changes to your variables after being created, you should give it a reference:

```
std::bind(A::function, std::cref(varA1));
```

Comment: Yes, the header declaration is to make the function available for, say, main.cpp. Anyway, I understood that i have to "wrap" the 'std::bind' inside a 'std::function'. Isn't there a way to make the binding itself visible outside the cpp file? I have also considered a functor instead of bindings. Is there any major performance difference between them?

Comment: You could use it like that: `using Type = decltype(std::bind(function, 1));` if you are always using the same function and parameters types, but it requires a declaration of the function before. If you do not want to declare it before, you need to add an abstraction that will take some resources at runtime (such as `std::function`). A functor will not be as efficient as the example before, but i suppose should be better than `std::function`. Only one way to be sure though: measure.